# php upload a file into current directory

Tags: php, file, append

I want to upload an mp3 file and add it into a directory on my server. I am executing the php code from the server directory I want to add the file to. This is what I have so far:

```
    $dir=basename(dirname(__FILE__));
    $folder = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
    $file_name = $_FILES['upload']['name'];
    //remember to remove this line
    $file_name = "test.mp3";
    $add_file[0] = "<a 
    href='//mydomain.com$folder/$dir/$file_name'>$file_name</a>";
    $path = "https://nerjabible.com$folder/$dir/";
```

so I have $add_file[0] and I have the $path to append to. I have tried put and write append, but they all seem to work by opening a file, I am already in the directory, I just want to append my linked file to the existing links in the directory.

The mp3 is in a directory on my PC as a hyperlink playable file and I am using a file upload script to obtain the file which ends up in $file_name but as a non linked file name, so i want to append this into the same directory the script is running from, but as a linked file.

[printscreen of the local and remote directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAr2U.png)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question: do you mean you want to add an mp3 file into your server's directory by providing the URL of the file?

Comment: pixeline Yes append the mp3 as a link append $file_name as a link into  $folder/$dir/  $file_name comes from a file upload routine

Comment: Can you provide an example of the links in the directory? because it can just be a txt file containing the URL.

Comment: added some more explaination and an image in the text

Comment: What is the point of `$file_name = "test.mp3"`, when that is absolutely not the name of the file on the server, according to your screenshot? You said in comment to the currently existing answer, that you had the part of moving the uploaded file to a permanent location already - so where is that? _That_ is the filename you need to use to link to the file.

Comment: I discovered the problem in the plupload script but I dont have the answer as described here in this post,  'Plupload unable to upload files over 940kb, this is the issue with larger files'